# can not increase google cloud gpu quota

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to increase the quota of gpus(all regions) in google cloud platform, but I always get the feedback from google team as the following:

> We have received your quota request for deeplearning-224014.
>   Unfortunately, we are unable to grant your quota increase at this time.

I want to know the reason and want to know how to resolve it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only the GCP customer service team can answer it.

Answer (score 0):

For non-technical inquiries like this, I suggest contacting the [Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact/), where they can assist you with the issue.